# R Subtracting columns within a list

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, subtraction

I'd like to subtract specific columns within a list. I'm still learning how to properly use the apply functions. For example, given

```
> b <- list(data.frame(12:16, 3*2:6), data.frame(10:14, 2*1:5))
> b

[[1]]
  X12.16 X3...2.6
1     12        6
2     13        9
3     14       12
4     15       15
5     16       18

[[2]]
  X10.14 X2...1.5
1     10        2
2     11        4
3     12        6
4     13        8
5     14       10
```

I'd like some function x so that I get

```
> x(b)

[[1]]
  X12.16 X3...2.6  <newcol>
1     12        6         6
2     13        9         4
3     14       12         2
4     15       15         0
5     16       18        -2

[[2]]
  X10.14 X2...1.5  <newcol>
1     10        2         8
2     11        4         7
3     12        6         6
4     13        8         5
5     14       10         4
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data.frames had nice and consistent names, you could use `transform` with `lapply`

```
b <- list(data.frame(a=12:16, b=3*2:6), data.frame(a=10:14, b=2*1:5))
lapply(b, transform, c=a-b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

```
lapply(b, function(x) {
  x[, 3] <- x[, 1] - x[, 2]
  x
})

[[1]]
  X12.16 X3...2.6 V3
1     12        6  6
2     13        9  4
3     14       12  2
4     15       15  0
5     16       18 -2

[[2]]
  X10.14 X2...1.5 V3
1     10        2  8
2     11        4  7
3     12        6  6
4     13        8  5
5     14       10  4
```

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(b, function(x) x %>% mutate(new_col = .[[1]]-.[[2]]))
```

**Result:**

```
[[1]]
  X12.16 X3...2.6 new_col
1     12        6       6
2     13        9       4
3     14       12       2
4     15       15       0
5     16       18      -2

[[2]]
  X10.14 X2...1.5 new_col
1     10        2       8
2     11        4       7
3     12        6       6
4     13        8       5
5     14       10       4
```